# use of contour and contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a list of points:

```
pointList = [ [x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], ... [xn,yn,zn]]
```

and I want to draw a contour plot of this set of points.

I try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pointList = [ [x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], ... [xn,yn,zn]]
x = [el[0] for el in pointList]
y = [el[1] for el in pointList]
z = [el[2] for el in pointList]
plt.contourf(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

but I have this exception:

```
TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.
```

This is strange because in the documentation of matplotlib I find:

```
Call signatures:
contour(Z)
make a contour plot of an array Z. The level values are chosen automatically.
contour(X,Y,Z)
X, Y specify the (x, y) coordinates of the surface
```

So I don't understand why it fails ...

Comment: Do your points actually create a surface? `X` and `Y` are the unique `x` and `y` values to use for the surface. It's not intended to be used for scattered data

Comment: not sure to understand. how should I do to "actually" create a surface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make contour of scatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764814/make-contour-of-scatter)

Comment: You have scattered data (it seems) so you'll need to convert it to a regular grid using the method in the duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either case, `contour(Z)`, or `contour(X,Y,Z)`, the input `Z` must be a 2D array.

If your data does not live on a grid, you either need to interpolate it to a grid or you cannot use contour.

An easy alternative is to use [`tricontour`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tricontour.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
pointList = [ [x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], ... [xn,yn,zn]]
pointList = np.array(pointList)
plt.tricontour(pointList[:,0],pointList[:,1],pointList[:,2])
plt.show()
```

There is a good example which compares `tricontour` with a `contour` of interpolated data: [tricontour_vs_griddata](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_vs_griddata.html).

You may also look at:

- [Plotting Isolines/contours in matplotlib from (x, y, z) data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702920/plotting-isolines-contours-in-matplotlib-from-x-y-z-data-set) (which has an easy example for both, tricontour and interpolated contour)
- [matplotlib contour/contourf of **concave** non-gridded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426095/matplotlib-contour-contourf-of-concave-non-gridded-data) (for the case that your data is concave)